# unable to Delete File in Android

Tags: java, android, file

I have tried my solution from StackOverflow but unable to delete file from android

I am getting run time permission. it is in Adapter

```
File file = new File(/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20190406-WA0004.mp4/VID-20190406-WA0004.mp4
);
                boolean deleted = file.delete();
                file.deleteOnExit();
                Log.d("Delete", String.valueOf(deleted));

                if (!deleted) {
                    boolean deleted2 = false;
                    deleted2 = file.getAbsoluteFile().delete();
                    Log.d("Delete", String.valueOf(deleted2));
                    if (!deleted2) {
                        String dir = file.getAbsolutePath();
                        File f0 = new File(dir, file.getName());
                        boolean d0 = f0.delete();
                        Log.d("Delete", String.valueOf(f0));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please share your error code

Comment: i am not getting error just on file.delete() i am getting false

Comment: Do you have permission to access the filesystem in your manifest?

Comment: I am getting  read and write extennal storage in manifest and runtime also

Comment: Try [Files.delete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) instead. It will throw an exception containing a helpful message.

Answer (score 0):

Add required permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml` if you didn't already:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then you should implement runtime permissions at `onCreate()` method in your MainActivity.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

Remove file if permission's granted

```
  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            // delete file
         break;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Also scan file from media scanner after f0.delete()

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{dir}, null, null);
```

Comment: I am getting  these  permission on runtime on start of application should i get every time delete fuction is called??

Comment: Yes. You should call runtime permissions at onCreate() of your main activity, if permissions are granted, call delete function otherwise application will crash.

Comment: yes I am getting runtime permission onCreate() and granted permissions